# Spring RestTemplate make a multipart request

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I've two microservices(built in spring-boot). Let's consider microservice `A` & microservice `B`.
I want to make a proxy call of multipart form request. For that I'm using RestTemplate. But I'm getting the error `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 406 null`.
It's working properly if I directly hit microservice `B`

Following is the code of RestController (microservice `A`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/holidays",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateHolidays(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    periodService.updateHolidays(file);
    return  new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

PeriodService Method:

```
public void updateHolidays(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File tempFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") +
                file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(tempFile);


        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        headers.set("Accept","application/json' {\"type\":\"formData\"}");

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("file", tempFile);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
                = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);


        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
                .exchange(holidayURL, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        LOGGER.info("updateHolidays: Time taken to execute rest:"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
    }
```

I tried removing `headers.set("Accept","application/json' {\"type\":\"formData\"}");` but it gave 400 null issue.

Let me know what I'm missing, or there is better way of doing it.

Comment: You have wrong accept header, let it empty, or set as `"Accept","application/json"`

Comment: It's still giving the issue `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null`

Comment: How do you call Service B directly?

Comment: I'm calling Service B directly using swagger-ui as well as postman & it's working fine. Structure of Service B endpoint: 

```@RequestMapping(value = "/holidays",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateHolidays(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        periodService.updateHolidays(file);
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
    }```